# Copying text from website, attaches link with text copied?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Sorry for the title not really sure how to explain it being that I don't fully understand how it works. I'm not a veteran coder so sorry if I should already know this. When I copy a quote from this site: http://stories-etc.com/engineers.htm#ixzz1ZtBtOfWv and then paste it somewhere it automatically attaches other text with the quote: read more and then provides the link to the site. I understand why they do it just not the way they are doing it. I tried to take a look at the code with firebug but everything seemed normal to me so assuming its something with php or JS?? Thanks for the help

Comment: Took another look and I may have found what I think is doing this, There is a js if statement: if (document.location.protocol=='http:' Am I correct in saying that?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7683786/1591669

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are using this JS service:
http://www.tynt.com/

It basically catches the selection event and attaches some more (hidden) data to the selection.

Answer (score 1):

Check its body listener, which has a 'oncopy' event listener

```
document.body.oncopy = function() {
    // replace the origin copy text
}
```