# When copying automatically add URL

Tags: html

I have seen on few websites that when you copy some text from there, and paste anywhere, it will add the URL of the page from where I copied the text.

For example:

```
This is text I copied.
```

and when I paste, I get:

```
This is text I copied.
Read more: http://example.com/abc/def
```

I'm just curious to know how this is done? How to add additional text in the copied text?

Example: Check [this question](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_did_the_Romans_deal_with_the_people_and_lands_that_they_conquered) (or any other) on answers.com. Copy the question text and paste. Tested with Firefox latest version.

Comment: Can you link to an actual example of someplace where that happens?

Comment: Also please include what browser(s) and OS(s) you've tested that functionality with.  Copy-Paste is typically an app/OS thing so you may be at the mercy of the app and OS being used.

Comment: @use966585 check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657951/copying-text-from-website-attaches-link-with-text-copied/7658150#7658150)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many online tools which provide this and other website/blog management utilities. Answer.com is also using one such service named **[tynt](http://www.tynt.com/)**. Open the link, scroll down to the bottom and you can see answer.com in featured clients ;).
[For more information.](http://www.smashingapps.com/2009/04/15/lets-find-out-whats-being-copied-from-your-site.html)

Answer (score 1):

[Zeroclipboard](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/wiki/Instructions) should help you modify the clipboard content. It's a flash movie that is hidden in the browser and exposes a JavaScript API to access the clipboard.

Example.

```
var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
clip.addEventListener('complete', function(client, text) {
    clip.setText(text + "Read more at www.");
});
```